# C++ Trying to do some kind of VARCHAR

Tags: c++, pointers, char, malloc, size

I am writing a small database manager, but I am having trouble doing something like VARCHAR type.

**It should work like this:** I have a 3 digits word, say "RPG", it should allocate enough size to put there RPG\0.

**What is happening:** It doesn't really matter if I use new, malloc(3), malloc(1), malloc(sizeof(char)*"RPG".size()), I can always use a much bigger region in memory. I tried checking it with malloc_size() and it always returns 16.

How can I do something that will allocate just enough space?

**EDIT:**

There's no specific codes, I'm trying things out and trying to figure how to do a char of varying size, but it would be something like this:

```
char * myChar1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned short int));
size_t howManyBytes = malloc_size(myChar1);
cout << "howManyBytes: " << howManyBytes << " bytes" << ends; //should say 2, instead it says 16
strcpy(myChar1,"HELLO HOW ARE YOU"); //shouldn't write the entire sentence as its bigger than 2 bytes
cout << "MYCHAR1: " << myChar1 << endl; //string
cout << "&MYCHAR1: " << &myChar1 << endl; //adress
cout << "*MYCHAR1: " << *myChar1 << endl; //first letter
```

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: No code. However, what I can already tell you is that *all* options you named (`new` and `malloc`) are almost certainly the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't need code, I edited with my last try, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on a 64-bit system, so the system allocates blocks of memory on 16-byte boundaries, so you are getting data allocated in multiples of 16.  Since every block allocated has to start on an address that's a multiple of 16, if it only gave you 4 bytes, the other 12 would not be usable anyway, since an allocated block could not start at the beginning of the 12-byte segment.